# Youtube videos are not working on Simple Product pages

Tags: magento2, product, simple-product, gallery

Any simple product that has a video assigned to it, will not play the video. If you are looking at the config product then videos play without issue.

Magento Version 2.3.5

Comment: This link can be helpful <br>
https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/catalog/product-video.html
<br>
Please describe more details of your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure youtube video URLs are defined in admin with the standard youtube.com URL. If you copy and paste the "share" URL, the youtu.be domain name in the URL will work on the admin panel but will not render properly on the PDP.